# Visual Studio load test error: Not able to execute load test with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

We are able to execute the load test with remote agent and controller using command prompt.But while running the load test with the visual studio, Getting the below error after certain time.

failed to queue test run :A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Let me know if some configurations has to be changed

Thanks 
Vihari

Comment: Please add Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

You are running into issues with accessing the Test Controller. Visual Studio Load Testing now supports running load tests in the cloud and also offers options to test apps behind firewall. Do refer to the below two blogs.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/23/testing-privateintranet-applications-using-cloud-based-load-testing/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/09/27/run-cloud-based-load-tests-using-your-own-machines-a-k-a-bring-your-own-subscription/